# MySql update value with multitalbe select

Tags: mysql, redmine

I need to write MySql script to automatically change member role in Redmine bugtracker every week or so. The problem is that I got user login and there is a really long way to get to the member role id (what you can figure out by hte nested select in find_in_set function).
I made this query, which displays actually what I want, but the table is not updated:

```
    SELECT REPLACE (role_id, '6', '4') as role_id 
    FROM member_roles 
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET( member_roles.member_id , (
        SELECT member_roles.member_id 
        FROM members,users,member_roles, roles 
        WHERE members.id=member_roles.member_id 
        AND members.user_id=users.id 
        AND member_roles.role_id=roles.id 
        AND users.login='user01'))
```

the result of this query is:

```
    -----------
    | role_id |
    -----------
    |    4    |
    -----------
```

I do not know how to update table instead of just displaying the result of this query.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'd love to know why you have to replace roles every week

Comment: quite simple. I have got one role little bit more privilaged then other, and that role is assigned every week to different user, so I have no choice but make a script to change the role instead changin it manually. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted the whole thing to the [multi-table syntax for UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html):

```
UPDATE member_roles 
JOIN members ON members.id = member_roles.member_id
JOIN users ON members.user_id = users.id
JOIN roles ON member_roles.role_id=roles.id 
SET member_roles.role_id = '4'
WHERE member_roles.role_id = '6'
AND users.login='user01'
```

Note that I've added the condition that `role_id = '6'` in order to allow for your `REPLACE()` statement - I'm not sure if you want that or not.

I hope I got all your conditions correct - you may want to test it like this first:

```
SELECT role_id
FROM member_roles 
JOIN members ON members.id = member_roles.member_id
JOIN users ON members.user_id = users.id
JOIN roles ON member_roles.role_id=roles.id 
WHERE member_roles.role_id = '6'
AND users.login='user01'
```

Check and make sure you are getting the same number of records that you were getting before.

Comment: it throws an error: '#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UDPATE member_roles 
SET role_id = '4'
WHERE role_id = '6'
AND FIND_IN_SET( m' at line 1 '

Comment: I had a typo - UPDATE, not UDPATE.

Comment: after correcting typo we have: `#1093 - You can't specify target table 'member_roles' for update in FROM clause `

Comment: OK, I've re-written the query to use a multi-table syntax, getting rid of your sub-query. Test the SELECT statement first - if it looks right then try the UPDATE query.

Comment: It looks like it is better to use join than nesting select queries. Your multi-table syntax did the job. The condition that `role_id = '6'` will prevent changing privilages of wrong role, so I will use it as well.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put that query in the update clause, for example:

```
UPDATE  member_roles SET YOUR_FIELD(S)_TO_UPDATE=VALUE(S) 
   WHERE role_id=(YOUR_SELECT_CLAUSE)
```

You can change the operator to IN in the where clause in case you have multiple results

Comment: Tried both: `UPDATE  member_roles SET role_id ='4' 
   IN (SELECT member_roles.member_id FROM members,users,member_roles, roles WHERE members.id=member_roles.member_id AND members.user_id=users.id AND member_roles.role_id=roles.id AND users.login='user01')` and `UPDATE  member_roles SET role_id ='4' 
   WHERE role_id=(select statement)` Both ways gave me same result: `#1093 - You can't specify target table 'member_roles' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: Just remove the table "member_roles" from the FROM clause in your SELECT query

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
UPDATE member_roles
set role_id='4'
WHERE FIND_IN_SET( member_roles.member_id , (
        SELECT member_roles.member_id 
        FROM members,users,member_roles, roles 
        WHERE members.id=member_roles.member_id 
        AND members.user_id=users.id 
        AND member_roles.role_id=roles.id 
        AND users.login='user01'))
```

Comment: unfortunatelly it gives error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM member_roles WHERE members.id = member_roles.member_id AND members.use' at line 2

Comment: UPDATE member_roles
set role_id='4'
WHERE role_id IN(
        SELECT member_roles.member_id 
        FROM members,users,member_roles, roles 
        WHERE members.id=member_roles.member_id 
        AND members.user_id=users.id 
        AND member_roles.role_id=roles.id 
        AND users.login='user01')